# What is the idiomatic way (if any) to refresh (repaint) a row in JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have instances of JTable who listen for some remote events, and depending on the type of event I want to lock/unlock a row with model index N. By *Locking a row* I mean setting the editable flag for all its cells to false. This is handled by my table model.

At the moment, I am calling `repaint()` because I did not want my table model to fire up the *updated* event, which is another alternative, but I am having a complex logic which is happening when the actual data in a row are changed, and did not want to trigger that logic.

Is there any other way?

Comment: who needs to know whether the editability is changed? Or the other way round: why do you need a repaint? And where/why/how do you call the repaint? The base problem is (as you already discovered) that notification of changes in meta-data isn't supported at all.

Comment: Well, the users need to "see" that row is locked, so they not attemp to modify some cell, and get frustrated to see it is not editable. :) I need to repaint after I change the editability flag for all the cells in the "locked" row. I am trying at the moment to fireTableChanged() with TableModelEvent of type 7 and will see if I can make table respond to it the way I need.

Comment: yeah, that's what I assumed - but you still didn't answer where you call the repaint :-) Anyway, in SwingX I would make a custom tableModel fire some custom event, some listener to that custom event that updates a HighlightPredicate of a Highlighter to turn on/off the visual clue for editability. As JXTable is listening to its Highlighters, it'll automagically update itself as needed :)

Comment: Ah sorry... I call the repaint in the event handler. When my Observer is notified that the record should be locked, i set the flags so MyTableModel.isCellEditable() returns false, and after that I call repaint(). It all works well, but I have a gut feeling that is not the best way to do this... I am thinking of very similar approach to what you have described above! :)

Answer (score 0):

Changes should be made directly to the `TableModel`. The TableModel will then invoke the appropriate `fireXXX()` method and the table will automatically repaint the rows affected.

Since it sounds like this "editable flag" is not visible on the table then there is really no reason to repaint the table, so you can override the TableModel to not generate any event when this flag is changed.

Comment: That is exactly what I do. Problem is that the only event I can fire (that makes sense) is the update event. Somehow it seems logical to relate update event with actual DATA update, not the editable state of particular cells...